# Force overwrite when saving to GCP bucket (pd.to_csv)

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a little problem that I cannot solve and would really appreciate any input on this. You see, whenever I've used `pd.to_csv()` to write a file to a folder, it has done what I expected to do, namely to overwrite any file with the same name.

I am now working solely working on GCP and I need to refresh tokens to access some API:s using existing ones. To do this is not any problem, but what I've done is save copies of all the API tokens in a dataframe that I store in a bucket. All my files have a datestamp:

**Saving**

```
base = datetime.date.today()
bucket_name_tokens = 'project-tokens'
bucket_path_tokens = 'gs://' + bucket_name_tokens
tokens.to_csv(bucket_path_tokens +'/tokens_{}.csv'.format(base))
```

**Reading**

```
bucket_name_tokens = 'project-tokens'
bucket_path_tokens = 'gs://' + bucket_name_tokens
tokens_new = pd.read_csv(bucket_path_tokens +'/tokens_{}.csv'.format(base))
```

I discovered that if I (for some reason) refresh my token and save the new one using the above code (on the same day, obviously), it **does not!** overwrite the older one with the same name.

I've looked everywhere for an explanation or for an option to `pandas.to_csv()` that I wasn't aware of without any luck.

Any idea on how to ensure that files are overwritten? Have I missed something?

**NOTE** This is also true of all the files I save in any of the buckets I have created.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just delete the old bersion before you upload the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't create a storage bucket with a retention.

retention is nice but it wont allow overwriting or deleting of items from the bucket, if turned off.

personally, I find it better to not have any retention.